# How to interpolate null values in a CnosDB select?

Tags: cnosdb

I have a data set that has a null column, I want to replace the null column with some other values, what should I do?

The example data:

```sql
❯ create table tab_1(fa bigint, fb double, tags(ta, tb, tc));
❯ insert into tab_1(time,ta,tb,fa,fb) values
('2022-12-31T00:01:00', 'a1', 'b1', 1, 111.0),
('2022-12-31T00:02:00', 'a1', 'b1', 2, 222.0),
('2022-12-31T00:03:00', 'a3', 'b1', 3, 333.0),
('2022-12-31T00:04:00', 'a3', 'b2', 1, 111.0),
('2022-12-31T00:05:00', 'a1', 'b2', 1, 111.0),
('2022-12-31T00:06:00', 'a1', 'b2', 2, 222.0),
('2022-12-31T00:07:00', 'a2', 'b2', 2, 222.0),
('2022-12-31T00:08:00', 'a2', 'b2', 3, 333.0);
❯ select * from tab_1;
+---------------------+----+----+----+----+-------+
| time                | ta | tb | tc | fa | fb    |
+--------------------------+----+----+----+-------+
| 2022-12-31T00:01:00 | a1 | b1 |    | 1  | 111.0 |
| 2022-12-31T00:02:00 | a1 | b1 |    | 2  | 222.0 |
| 2022-12-31T00:03:00 | a3 | b1 |    | 3  | 333.0 |
| 2022-12-31T00:04:00 | a3 | b2 |    | 1  | 111.0 |
| 2022-12-31T00:05:00 | a1 | b2 |    | 1  | 111.0 |
| 2022-12-31T00:06:00 | a1 | b2 |    | 2  | 222.0 |
| 2022-12-31T00:07:00 | a2 | b2 |    | 2  | 222.0 |
| 2022-12-31T00:08:00 | a2 | b2 |    | 3  | 333.0 |
+--------------------------+----+----+----+-------+
```

I have tried `CASE WHEN` to fill column `tc`:

```sql
❯ SELECT ta, tb, CASE WHEN tc=null THEN 0 END tc, fa, fb FROM tab_1;
+----+----+----+----+-------+
| ta | tb | tc | fa | fb    |
+----+----+----+----+-------+
| a2 | b2 |    | 2  | 222.0 |
| a2 | b2 |    | 3  | 333.0 |
| a1 | b1 |    | 1  | 111.0 |
| a1 | b1 |    | 2  | 222.0 |
| a3 | b1 |    | 3  | 333.0 |
| a3 | b2 |    | 1  | 111.0 |
| a1 | b2 |    | 1  | 111.0 |
| a1 | b2 |    | 2  | 222.0 |
+----+----+----+----+-------+
```

What should I do if I want to get result set like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+-------+
| ta | tb | tc | fa | fb    |
+----+----+----+----+-------+
| a2 | b2 | cc | 2  | 222.0 |
| a2 | b2 | cc | 3  | 333.0 |
| a1 | b1 | cc | 1  | 111.0 |
...
```